# Generate an event context menu

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I had already developed the js code that allowed me to display the context menu through another action. For example, by left clicking or pressing a key.
I managed to do what I wanted for most elements except for some like the mails in gmail or Hotmail. When you right-click, there is a small menu with "archive" or "mark as unread" for example. It's not the classic menu which appears.
What I would like to do is force the display of the classic menu on these too.
Here is the code I have so far to generate my contextmenu event :

```
window.document.addEventListener("click", associate, false);
window.document.addEventListener("mousedown", associate, false);
window.document.addEventListener("mouseup", associate, false);
        
var associate = function(event)
{
    var element = event.srcElement||event.target;
    element.addEventListener("click", context, true);
    element.addEventListener("mousedown", context, true);
    element.addEventListener("mouseup", context, true);
};

var context = function(event)
{
    if(event.button == 0)
    {
        var element = event.srcElement||event.target;
        menu(element, event);
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
};

var menu = function(element, event)
{
    var evt = element.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evt.initMouseEvent('contextmenu', true, true, element.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, event.screenX, event.screenY, event.clientX, event.clientY, false, false, false, false, 2, null);
    element.dispatchEvent(evt);
};
```

With that, on an email in gmail for example I still have the special gmail context menu when I left click.
Do you have any idea about how I could do ?

Comment: You need to create HTML elements that look like a menu.

Comment: @SLaks But how could I retrieve the elements of the classic context menu ?

Comment: You can't.  That's totally impossible.

Comment: This is what I begin to think...

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the specific element or class of elements that have the custom context menu, and target them in your event listeners.
Disable or remove the event listeners attached to the custom context menus for those elements.

```js
window.document.addEventListener("click", associate, false);
window.document.addEventListener("mousedown", associate, false);
window.document.addEventListener("mouseup", associate, false);

var associate = function (event) {
    var element = event.srcElement || event.target;
    element.addEventListener("click", context, true);
    element.addEventListener("mousedown", context, true);
    element.addEventListener("mouseup", context, true);

    // Disable Gmail or Hotmail custom context menus
    if (element.classList.contains("gmail-class") || element.classList.contains("hotmail-class")) {
        element.removeEventListener("contextmenu", null, true);
    }
};

var context = function (event) {
    if (event.button == 0) {
        var element = event.srcElement || event.target;
        menu(element, event);
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
};

var menu = function (element, event) {
    var evt = element.ownerDocument.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evt.initMouseEvent("contextmenu", true, true, element.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, event.screenX, event.screenY, event.clientX, event.clientY, false, false, false, false, 2, null);
    element.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

You also need to replace **"gmail-class"** and **"hotmail-class"** with the actual class names or attributes that Gmail and Hotmail use for their custom context menus.

Keep in mind that webmail services like Gmail and Hotmail might have obfuscated class names or frequently update their front-end code. This could make it challenging to identify the correct elements or maintain compatibility with your custom context menu.